# Is there a way to detect when a domain is caught by the Hosts file?

Tags: windows, dns, hosts-file, domain-name

On Windows, I use the etc/hosts file to block some domains, for example because they are often used to serve ads. But sometimes, a program tries to connect to a blocked domain for a legitimate reason and fails. It is often unclear what is causing the program to fail at first (e.g. it could be my AV, firewall, a network issue, some other conflicting app...) and I waste time troubleshooting before finding that the hosts file is the culprit.

Is there a way to log, or perhaps receive a Windows notification, when a program attempts to reach a domain that is listed in the hosts file? Ideally it would record the timestamp, name of the program, and the domain it tried to reach.

Comment: Unlikely.  You might be better off running your own authorative DNS server with customised zones, and using logging on that.  Maybe DNSMasq?

Comment: BTW, Windows *ignores* blocking of certain URL's in the *hosts* file. See https://petri.com/windows-10-ignoring-hosts-file-specific-name-resolution/ .

Comment: Using the hosts file to block ads is a horrible way to block ads.  Those domains change way to often for that approach to be effective.  There also is a huge performance hit when the file is fairly large.